# How to search term in a certain range in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, query-parser

I want to search terms which is in `[0, 10]`, and terms are from the field "CityId" that is stored as Integer. What I have written is below:

```
String queryStr = "CityId : [0, 10]";
Query query = parser.parse(queryStr);
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(queryStr);
```

Comment: And what is the reult of your querry? If you dont want to parse a querry string you can build a NumericRangeQuery like this: NumericRangeQuery.  newIntRange(0,10,true, true)

Answer (score 2):

The standard QueryParser does not support numeric ranges.  The range queries supported by the QueryParser are Lexicographic, rather than numeric.  You will need to use a [NumericRangeQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html) for this:

```
Query query = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("CityId", 0, 10, true, true);
```

Also, might be good to refer to the [QueryParser documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Range_Searches) for what Lucene's query syntax looks like.  Range queries upper and lower bounds are not separated by a comma.  It should look like `myField:[begin TO end]` (again, though, this will not be a *numeric* range).